# Regex matches under g++ 4.9 but fails under g++-5.3.1

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, g++

I am tokenizing a string with a regex; this works normally under `g++-4.9`, but fails under `g++-5.3.1`.

I have the following txt file:

```
0001-SCAND ==> "Scandaroon" (from Philjumba)
0002-KINVIN ==> "King's Vineyard" (from Philjumba)
0003-HANNI ==> "Hannibal: Rome vs. Carthage" (from Philjumba)
0004-LOX ==> "Lords of Xidit" (from Philjumba)
```

which I am tokenizing using regular expressions, by spaces, quotation marks pairs and parentheses pairs. For example, the first line should be tokenized as follows:

```
0001-SCAND
==>
"Scandaroon"
(from Philjumba)
```

I have written the following `std::regex`:

```
std::regex FPAT("(\\S+)|(\"[^\"]*\")|(\\([^\\)]+\\))";
```

And I am tokenizing the string with:

```
std::vector<std::string>
split( const std::string & input, const std::regex & regex ) {

        std::sregex_token_iterator
                first{input.begin(), input.end(), regex, 0},
                last;

        return {first, last};
}
```

This returns the matches. Under `g++-4.9` the string is tokenized as requested, but under `g++-5.3.1` it's tokenized as follows:

```
0001-SCAND
==>
"Scandaroon"
(from
Philjumba)
```

or the third line is tokenized as follows:

```
0003-HANNI
==>
"Hannibal:
Rome
vs.
Carthage"
(from
Philjumba)
```

What could the issue be?

---

edit: I am calling the function as follows:

```
std::string line("0001-SCAND ==> \"Scandaroon\" (from Philjumba)");
auto elems = split( line, FPAT );
```

---

edit: following feedback from @xaxxon, I replaced returning the iterator by a vector, but it's still not working correctly under `g++-5.3`.

```
std::vector<std::string>
split( const std::string & input, const std::regex & regex ) {

        std::sregex_token_iterator
                first{input.begin(), input.end(), regex, 0},
                last;

        std::vector< std::string > elems;
        elems.reserve( std::distance(first,last) );

        for ( auto it = first; it != last; ++ it ) {
                //std::cout << (*it) << std::endl;
                elems.push_back( *it );
        }

        return elems;
}
```

Comment: BTW, raw string may help to avoid extra escaping: `R"((\S+)|("[^"]*")|(\([^\)]+\)))"`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thank you, it should be fixed now. Added an extra ``)`` during copy/paste, apparently.

Comment: Please post how you are calling this function -- if you're calling it with an rvalue as the first parameter, the string is likely not valid by the time you're using the iterators.  The actual memory allocation behind the scenes can easily change across compiler versions causing memory that happened to still look good in an old version to not look good in a newer version.

Comment: at https://regex101.com/#pcre, `R"(("[^\"]*\")|(\([^\)])+\)|(\S+))"` works as expected, but not `R"((\S+)|("[^\"]*\")|(\([^\)])+\))"`... (`\S+` at the end or at the beginning).

Comment: @xaxxon Added, thank you for your feedback. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression is *Eager*

so for a regular expression `"Set|SetValue"` and the text `"SetValue"`, regex founds `"Set"`.

You have to choose order carefully:

```
std::regex FPAT(R"(("[^\"]*\")|(\([^\)])+\)|(\S+))");
```

`\S+` at the end to be the last considered.

An other alternative is to use not the default option (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type)
and use `std::::regex::extended`

```
std::regex FPAT(R"((\S+)|("[^\"]*\")|(\([^\)])+\))", std::::regex::extended);
```

So it seems that g++-5.3.1 has fixed a bug since g++-4.9 in this regard.

Comment: Yes, that's indeed the issue! In fact I learned a few days ago about regexes being "Eager" and fixed a similar bug, but forgot about this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't post enough for me to know for sure (you updated it showing you are calling it with an lvalue, so this post probably doesn't pertain, but I'll leave it up unless people want me to take it down), but if you're doing what I did, you forgot that the iterators are into the source string and that string is no longer valid.

You could remove the `const` from `input`, but it's so damn convenient to be able to put an rvalue there, so.....

Here's what I do to avoid this - I return a unique_ptr to something that looks like the results, but I hide the actual source string along with it so the strsing can't go away before I'm done using it.  This is likely UB, but I think it will work virtually all the time:

```
// Holds a regex match as well as the original source string so the matches remain valid as long as the 
// caller holds on to this object - but it acts just like a std::smatch
struct MagicSmatch {
    std::smatch match;
    std::string data;

    // constructor makes a copy of the string and associates
    // the copy's lifetime with the iterators into the string (the smatch)
    MagicSmatch(const std::string & data) : data(data)
    {}
};

// this deleter knows about the hidden string and makes sure to delete it
// this cast is probably UB because std::smatch isn't a standard layout type
struct MagicSmatchDeleter {
    void operator()(std::smatch * smatch) {
        delete reinterpret_cast<MagicSmatch *>(smatch);
    }
};


// the caller just thinks they're getting a smatch ptr.. but we know the secret
std::unique_ptr<std::smatch, MagicSmatchDeleter> regexer(const std::regex & regex, const std::string & source)
{
    auto magic_smatch = new MagicSmatch(source);
    std::regex_search(magic_smatch->data, magic_smatch->match, regex);
    return std::unique_ptr<std::smatch, MagicSmatchDeleter>(reinterpret_cast<std::smatch *>(magic_smatch));

}
```

as long as you call it as auto results = regexer(....) then it's quite easy to use, though `results` is a pointer, not a proper `smatch`, so the `[]` syntax doesn't work as nicely.